# What is the correct syntax to pass in an object into ngResource .save()?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, ngresource

I am trying to pass the `item` object into my `$resource` function, which will save the item to my database. However, when I send the $resource.save(item) it returns a `Error Code 500 Internal Server Error. Item validation failed.`

This is the object, pretty standard:

```
var item = {
   "title": "Item Title",
   "desc": "Item Description"
}
```

My client side controller:

```
App.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $resource){
    $scope.resourceUrl = $resource('http://localhost:3000/items');
        $scope.postItem = function(item){
             $scope.resourceUrl.save(item).$promise                 // Should item be passed in like this?
             .then(function(data){ //success function
                console.log('Posted item called ' + item.title);
             },function(error){ //error function
                console.log(error);
             });
        };
};
```

My server side routing:

```
router.post('/items', function(req, res, next){
        var item = new Item(req.body);

        item.save(function(err, item){
            if(err){return next(err)}
            res.json(item);
        });
    });
```

When I try `$scope.resourceUrl.save().$promise` with no `item`, it will post an `item` but with no data. What is the correct syntax for passing in my `item` object?

Comment: `$resource` gives you a whole bunch of methods that are overkill for your example. Just use `$http` as `$http.post('/someUrl', item, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

Comment: Even using `$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);` gives the same error.

Comment: try `$scope.resourceUrl.save({},item)`

Comment: @Chandermani that also resulted in the same error